# Calling each vector in vector<vector<pair<int, int>>>

Tags: c++

I have a set of values saved into:

```
vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> subsets
```

If I wanted to output the values from each vector within the vector. How would I go about doing that?
vector<pair<int, int>> would be in the format <(1, 2) (2, 3) (5,0)>

```
vector<pair<int, int>> = <(1, 2) (2, 3) (5,0)>
```

subsets would contain several sets of vectors

```
[1] <(1, 2) (2, 3) (5,0)>
[2] <(1, 2) (4, 8) > 
[3] <(0, 1) (5, 5) (1, 1)> 
etc...
```

If anyone has suggestions to do this another way, please share them! Data structures in C++ is a bit of a mystery to me.

Edit:
I was able to get to vector<pair<int, int>>, by calling the first and second of the pair.

```
for (pair<int, int> p : items)
        cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ") ";
```

Vectors within the vector don't seem to be recognized by subset.at(0) call.

Comment: what did you try and how did it fail? Do you know how to iterate elements of a vector? Do you know how to print elements of a pair?

Comment: maybe it gets less mysterious when you read some documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> subsets{
        {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5,0}},
        {{1, 2}, {4, 8}}, 
        {{0, 1}, {5, 5}, {1, 1}}
    };

    for(auto& inner : subsets) {    // loop over the outer vector
        auto it = inner.begin();    // get iterator for the inner vector

        std::cout << '<';
        if(it != inner.end()) {

            // print the first pair
            std::cout << '(' << it->first << ',' << it->second << ')';

            // print the rest of the pairs
            for(++it; it != inner.end(); ++it) {
                std::cout << " (" << it->first << ',' << it->second << ')';
            }
        }
        std::cout << ">\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<(1,2) (2,3) (5,0)>
<(1,2) (4,8)>
<(0,1) (5,5) (1,1)>
```